# MySQL + phpMyAdmin decimal defaults to zero every time

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, decimal

When I add new column into my table and set data type to `decimal`, for example `10.2`, upon saving convert it to `10.0`.

How can I do this? Can someone provide SQL request to create table with decimal data type? I want to run it and see if it will work like this.

Comment: Why not just make it a int and convert it before saving to database?  Alternatively set the decimal places of field to 0.  That might work

Comment: Show the current schema of table

Comment: dreza how can i convert?

Answer (score 1):

Check your table schema. for decimal datatypes number of `decimals (D)` is required.

`DECIMAL(M,D)` - An unpacked floating-point number that cannot be unsigned. Defining the display `length (M)` and the n`umber of decimals (D)` is **required**.

Example schema

```
 Create Table Stu(
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 field_name decimal(10,2) default NULL
);
```

Comment: In other words, you need a comma, not a decimal between the two digit lengths. You should specify 10,2 not 10.2 -- the later is interpreted as a single parameter (cast to integer 10) and so defines only the number of digits to the left.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when using the phpmyadmin interface to edit a table. Everytime I tried to change the field decimal(6) to decimal(6,2); when I hit go it would just come back with decimal(6) everytime. 
If all else fails edit the code it generates directly. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to change your decimal value:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

Comment: so this is a bug in phpmyadmin interface?

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL Workbench instead of the simplest phpMyAdmin interface, you get exactly what you want.

It´s free, very powerful, and you can be downloaded from 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/